WiX .msi doesn't uninstall nor stop installed services on uninstall
I have a WiX built .msi file which, when ran on my local account, successfully installs two services after having asked for admin credentials.
Then, when right-clicking the .msi file and ask for uninstall, the uninstall process asks for admin credentials again and ends without any warning/error, but the two services are still there and running.
Do you think that it is a problem of config (more certainly... I hope) ? Here it is: POC created with Visual Studio 2022 ("MSI package" project), .NET 8.0, WiX version 5.0.0
Package.wxs:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Define the variables in "$(var.*) expressions" -->
<?include ../config.xml ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Package Name="$(ServiceDisplayName)"
             Manufacturer="$(Manufacturer)"
             Version="$(Version)"
             UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
             Compressed="true">

        <!-- Allow upgrades and prevent downgrades -->
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />

        <!-- Define the directory structure -->
        <StandardDirectory Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">

                <!-- Create a folder inside program files -->
                <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">

                    <!-- Create a folder within the parent folder given the name -->
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Services" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </StandardDirectory>

        <!-- Tell WiX to install the files -->
        <Feature Id="Service" Title="Service Setup" Level="1">
            <!-- The files inside this DirectoryRef are linked to
             the Service directory via INSTALLFOLDER -->
            
            <!-- Create a single component which is the Service.exe file -->
            <Component Id="ServiceExecutable" Bitness="always64">

                <!-- Copies the Service.exe file using the
                     project reference preprocessor variables -->
                <File Id="Service.exe"
                      Source="$(var.Service.TargetDir)publish\$(ServiceProjectName).exe"
                      KeyPath="true" />

                <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
                <RemoveFile Id="uninstallService" Name="*.*" On="both" />

                <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
                <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                                Type="ownProcess"
                                Name="$(ServiceId)"
                                DisplayName="$(ServiceDisplayName)"
                                Description="$(ServiceDescription)"
                                Start="auto"
                                ErrorControl="normal" />

                <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
                <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                                Start="install"
                                Stop="both"
                                Remove="uninstall"
                                Name="$(ServiceId)"
                                Wait="true" />
            </Component>
        </Feature>

        <!-- Create a single component which is the ServiceController.exe file -->
        <Feature Id="ServiceController" Title="Service Setup" Level="1">
            <Component Id="ServiceControllerExecutable" Bitness="always64">
                
                <!-- Copies the ServiceController.exe file using the
                        project reference preprocessor variables -->
                <File Id="ServiceController.exe"
                        Source="$(var.ServiceController.TargetDir)publish\$(ServiceControllerProjectName).exe"
                        KeyPath="true" />

                <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
                <RemoveFile Id="uninstallServiceController" Name="*.*" On="both" />


                <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->
                <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceControllerInstaller"
                                Type="ownProcess"
                                Name="$(ServiceControllerId)"
                                DisplayName="$(ServiceControllerDisplayName)"
                                Description="$(ServiceControllerDescription)"
                                Start="auto"
                                ErrorControl="normal" />

                <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
                <ServiceControl Id="StartServiceController"
                                Start="install"
                                Stop="both"
                                Remove="uninstall"
                                Name="$(ServiceControllerId)"
                                Wait="true" />
            </Component>
        </Feature>

    </Package>
</Wix>

config.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Include>
    
    <?define ServiceId = "3783A353-047F-4767-9C1A-567280AB3453" ?>
    <?define ServiceDisplayName = ".CGM Service" ?>
    <?define ServiceDescription = "A CGM jokes service" ?>
    <?define ServiceProjectName = "$(var.Service.ProjectName)" ?>

    <?define ServiceControllerId = "4ADA6A42-1AC3-417C-92D0-F87D4D6D584B" ?>
    <?define ServiceControllerDisplayName = ".CGM Service Controller" ?>
    <?define ServiceControllerDescription = "A CGM service controller" ?>
    <?define ServiceControllerProjectName = "$(var.ServiceController.ProjectName)" ?>
    
    <?define Manufacturer = "CGM" ?>
    <?define Version = "1.0.0.0" ?>
    <?define UpgradeCode = "9ED3FF33-8718-444E-B44B-69A2344B7E98" ?>

</Include>

EDIT: what is strange is that after uninstall, in the Windows logs, I see only 2 entries regarding only the first process (no entry for the second service):

"Product: .CGM Service -- Removal completed successfully."

"Windows Installer a supprimé le produit. Nom du produit : .CGM Service. Version du produit : 1.0.0.0. Langue du produit : 1033. Fabricant : CGM. Réussite de la suppression ou état d’erreur : 0." in English : "success in deletion or error state : 0")


